# coding standards in yii framework

Tags: php, yii, coding-style

is there any coding standard which follows yii framework, and where it is specified

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can find them in Yii basic Documents

[Yii Basic Convention](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/basics.convention)

Answer (score 6):

The following code style is used for Yii 1.x development: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii/wiki/Core-framework-code-style

CodeSniffer Coding Standard Repo: https://github.com/Ardem/yii-coding-standard

Answer (score 1):

Just you can see core files in this framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Yii2 coding standard.

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/wiki/Core-framework-code-style